Add three lines to get a bird and add four to get a metal

TEXT
Add exactly 3 straight lines to turn these five lines into a bird.
Add exactly 4 straight lines to turn the same into a metal.
HINT

 Think Greek


Voting to reopen because I feel there are a very limited number of answers that can objectively be proven to be correct.

@MacGyver88 Voting to leave closed because the array of answers actually posted down below shows that there are all manner of different answers that seem equally valid.

@Randal'Thor No doubt, but there can't be many more.  Who's to know, I guess.

My solution:

 

Which spells

PIPIT, a type of bird (spelled using Greek letter Pi), as well as FE when rotated 90 degrees, the atomic symbol for iron (although the E should technically be lowercase).

An alternative for the second one could be:

 


 which spells Ag when rotated 90 degrees, the atomic symbol for silver (with proper capitalization).


I agree that based off the later hint, your first solution is very likely what the OP intended. I do wonder though if there is a similar possibility for the second - best I've got so far is rot13(V EUB A tvivat VEBA) but I'm not 100% satisfied with it yet...

Although I accepted this solution, the second part was imagined differently by me. Z RGN Y  RGN orvat U

@RogerA well, then for the second part I would have written "turn it into metal" instead of "turn it into a metal" which (to me) requests a specific metal.

Here are answers to the questions which each use different rebus techniques...

 

 1. Add 3 lines to make "H+N", i.e. H + 'EN', or HEN, a bird.

 2. Add 4 lines to make "|IUM", where the first symbol is the 'bar' or 'pipe' character, giving us BARIUM, a metal.


We can add lines like so

 

to make

LOON and IRON.


I admire your thinking. However I was hoping for non joined letters.

Something like this?

 Use the lines to draw where your fingers must be to make a bird or metal.



Just for fun, here is yet another idea (however, ignoring the tag rebus and OP's hint).

 if you are tolerant with font, alignment and orientation... 

 which should read GULL and ZINC

